# Net 7 NativeLibrary: Load different lib versions

Tags: linux, docker, shared-libraries, c#-native-library

We have an service (.net 7, docker, Debian 11) which loads native (so-lib). The Libs exists in different versions. We load and free them via:

```
IntPtr handle = NativeLibrary.Load(_libFileName);
NativeLibrary.Free(handle );
```

Those so-libs have different macros init. If I now load the oldest Lib (Version 1.0.0) at first then for all newer version of that lib the updated macros are not rerun. It seems to me that all global code in all libs are running only once. Is there a good way to unload a native lib completely to re-load it in a new version.

I tried already to create a own instance `AssemblyLoadContext` (With `isCollectible:true`) and load the libs with a own `AssemblyLoadContext` and Unload it after that but the still new full released.